# DSN not able to connect to a remote SQL server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, odbc, dsn

I am moving all my existing applications to a new web server, applications use a DSN based connection using ODBC driver.

On the new server I am trying build DSN which connect's to remote SQL Server, but I am getting  the error :

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.
Invalid connection string attribute
```

Connection string is : `"Dsn=dsnName;uid=userID;pwd=pswd;Provider=SQLOLEDB;Integrated Security=SSPI"`

It works fine on my local P.C, but I get this error while establishing DSN on the web server.

If I specify the port number along with the Server name (servername, 6000) then connection went's thru but my application throw the same error.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Try using connection string as follows:

Server=dsnName;uid=userID;pwd=pswd;Provider=SQLOLEDB;Integrated Security=SSPI"

or try using

Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;Integrated Security=SSPI;
User ID=myDomain\myUsername;Password=myPassword;

Comment: I still need to stick to DSN based connection, The first option didn't worked, second one works but it a SQL Remote Connection bypassing the DSN.